# How to disable certain fields in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I use Firebase Analytics and the URL (aka `page_referrer` in analytics) might reveal which user is behind the event. Can I somehow disable certain fields in an event like `page_referrer`?

Check this example below. `page_referrer` is localhost because of my development environment. But I can see the full URL which could reveal from which user this event is.

[image]

Comment: Are you exporting the analytics data to BigQuery?

Comment: No (not yet), I just view them in the Firebase Analytics Console

Comment: It is not possible to disable such fields in firebase analytics. But if you are exporting the analytics data to Big Query, you can restrict access to the raw data in Big Query and create a view which non-trusted parties have access to.

Comment: Ok, understood, thx